# Searching for uiswitch for ios 7 with text or image options

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uiswitch

iOS 7 brings us switches without text at all, removing any effect of "onImage" and "offImage" properties we had in iOS 6.  I've tried to use DCRoundSwitch.. but it crashes the app.  Has anyone found a successful replacement for a UISwitch that has text (in my case, "YES"/"NO").

Comment: I have DCRoundSwitch working with iOS 7; it did take some

Answer (score 3):

You have many alternative of UISwitch:

1. [Cocoacontrols search switch](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=switch)
2. [code4app switch section](http://code4app.com/category/switch)